# Migrating project from java 8 to Java11 ,getting the errors package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module for org.w3c.dom.Document

Tags: java

My application is spring boot application when i am migrating java8 to java11,getting the following error messages "package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module  for org.w3c.dom.Document,org.w3c.dom.Node,org.w3c.dom.NodeList".

I have comment out xerces dependency in pom.xml and still getting the same above error. Please help me how to resolve the issue.

I am using Eclipse IDE

### pom.xml

```
   <properties>
     <java.version>11</java.version>
     <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
       <profile>
         <id>dev</id>
         <dependencies>
           <dependency>
             <groupid>org.apache.activemq</group>
             <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
          <dependency>
    </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
           <dependency>
             <groupid>org.springframwork.boot</group>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
          </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupid>org.springframwork.boot</group>
             <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
             <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupid>org.springframwork.boot</group>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
          </dependency>
     <dependency>
             <groupid>org.springframwork.boot</group>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersy</artifactId>
          </dependency>
    <dependency>
             <groupid>org.springframwork.boot</group>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
             <groupid>org.apache.camel</group>
             <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
          </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. You may find the site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section and this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) checklist useful guidance for asking a good question. It is easier for people to help you if you include the code that you've worked on to solve the problem and ideally provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is not a full `pom.xml`